# Onclicking listview item, whole background color of row changes instead of just the border (Using Card UI Layout)

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using CardUI layout for listview. Everything is working alright excpet when i click on a listview item,whole background color of that listview row changes instead of just the border area created by card UI.

Here is my code.

**Listview Items:**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    >
    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_background">
     <ImageView
           ...
           /> 

    <TextView
        ...

        />
     <TextView
        ...
        />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The extra linearlayout is used to create left/right margins, as listview ignores layout params otherwise.

**list_item_background**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_pressed" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_pressed" android:state_active="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background"/>
</selector>
```

**background_pressed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:dither="true">
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#CCC" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
            android:dither="true">
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ff00ddff" />
            <padding android:bottom="6dp"
                android:left="4dp"
                android:right="4dp"
                android:top="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I have no idea, where from this background dark blue color is coming??
Any suggestions Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is the list selector under your item, setting `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"` in the ListView should work.

Comment: Wow!.. thanks..worked perfectly...never came across this default listselector nonsense...:)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a padding to the ListView instead of a margin to the items.